# Pandas DataFrame Window Function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to manipulate my data frame similar to how you would using SQL window functions.  Consider the following sample set:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit' : ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'grape', 'grape', 'grape'],
               'test' : [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
               'analysis' : ['full', 'full', 'partial', 'full', 'full', 'partial', 'full', 'full', 'partial'],
               'first_pass' : [12.1, 7.1, 14.3, 19.1, 17.1, 23.4, 23.1, 17.2, 19.1],
               'second_pass' : [20.1, 12.0, 13.1, 20.1, 18.5, 22.7, 14.1, 17.1, 19.4],
               'units' : ['g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'],
               'order' : [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1]})
```

```
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| fruit  | test | analysis | first_pass | second_pass | order | units |
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| apple  |    1 | full     | 12.1       | 20.1        |     2 | g     |
| apple  |    2 | full     | 7.1        | 12.0        |     1 | g     |
| apple  |    1 | partial  | 14.3       | 13.1        |     3 | g     |
| orange |    1 | full     | 19.1       | 20.1        |     2 | g     |
| orange |    2 | full     | 17.1       | 18.5        |     1 | g     |
| orange |    1 | partial  | 23.4       | 22.7        |     3 | g     |
| grape  |    1 | full     | 23.1       | 14.1        |     3 | g     |
| grape  |    2 | full     | 17.2       | 17.1        |     2 | g     |
| grape  |    1 | partial  | 19.1       | 19.4        |     1 | g     |
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

I'd like to add a few columns:

- a boolean column to indicate whether the second_pass value for that test and analysis is the highest amongst all fruit types.
- another column that lists which fruits had the highest second_pass values for each test and analysis combination.

Using this logic, I'd like to get the following table:

```
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| fruit  | test | analysis | first_pass | second_pass | order | units | highest |   highest_fruits    |
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| apple  |    1 | full     | 12.1       | 20.1        |     2 | g     | true    | ["apple", "orange"] |
| apple  |    2 | full     | 7.1        | 12.0        |     1 | g     | false   | ["orange"]          |
| apple  |    1 | partial  | 14.3       | 13.1        |     3 | g     | false   | ["orange"]          |
| orange |    1 | full     | 19.1       | 20.1        |     2 | g     | true    | ["apple", "orange"] |
| orange |    2 | full     | 17.1       | 18.5        |     1 | g     | true    | ["orange"]          |
| orange |    1 | partial  | 23.4       | 22.7        |     3 | g     | true    | ["orange"]          |
| grape  |    1 | full     | 23.1       | 22.1        |     3 | g     | false   | ["orange"]          |
| grape  |    2 | full     | 17.2       | 17.1        |     2 | g     | false   | ["orange"]          |
| grape  |    1 | partial  | 19.1       | 19.4        |     1 | g     | false   | ["orange"]          |
+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

I'm new to pandas, so I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Wish I can help further but swamped at the moment. Off the top of my head, `g = df.groupby(['test','analysis'])['second_pass'].agg('idxmax')` will give you the indices of the rows with the maximum value for `second_pass` grouped by `test` and `analysis`. I don't know right now if it can detect ties though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `boolean` values where `second_pass` equals the `group` `max`, as `idxmax` only returns the first occurrence of the `max`:

```
df['highest'] = df.groupby(['test', 'analysis'])['second_pass'].transform(lambda x: x == np.amax(x)).astype(bool)
```

and then use `np.where` to capture all `fruit` values that have a `group` `max`, and `merge` the result into your `DataFrame` like so:

```
highest_fruits = df.groupby(['test', 'analysis']).apply(lambda x: [f for f in np.where(x.second_pass == np.amax(x.second_pass), x.fruit.tolist(), '').tolist() if f!='']).reset_index()
df =df.merge(highest_fruits, on=['test', 'analysis'], how='left').rename(columns={0: 'highest_fruit'})
```

finally, for your follow up:

```
first_pass = df.groupby(['test', 'analysis']).apply(lambda x: {fruit: x.loc[x.fruit==fruit, 'first_pass'] for fruit in x.highest_fruit.iloc[0]}).reset_index()
df =df.merge(first_pass, on=['test', 'analysis'], how='left').rename(columns={0: 'first_pass_highest_fruit'})
```

to get:

```
  analysis  first_pass   fruit  order  second_pass  test units highest  \
0     full        12.1   apple      2         20.1     1     g    True   
1     full         7.1   apple      1         12.0     2     g   False   
2  partial        14.3   apple      3         13.1     1     g   False   
3     full        19.1  orange      2         20.1     1     g    True   
4     full        17.1  orange      1         18.5     2     g    True   
5  partial        23.4  orange      3         22.7     1     g    True   
6     full        23.1   grape      3         14.1     1     g   False   
7     full        17.2   grape      2         17.1     2     g   False   
8  partial        19.1   grape      1         19.4     1     g   False   

     highest_fruit             first_pass_highest_fruit  
0  [apple, orange]  {'orange': [19.1], 'apple': [12.1]}  
1         [orange]                   {'orange': [17.1]}  
2         [orange]                   {'orange': [23.4]}  
3  [apple, orange]  {'orange': [19.1], 'apple': [12.1]}  
4         [orange]                   {'orange': [17.1]}  
5         [orange]                   {'orange': [23.4]}  
6  [apple, orange]  {'orange': [19.1], 'apple': [12.1]}  
7         [orange]                   {'orange': [17.1]}  
8         [orange]                   {'orange': [23.4]}
```

Comment: As a follow up question, is there a way to pull first_pass values into a new column based off of the highest_fruits.  For example, grapes' **full** analysis and **test** 1 (idx: 6) yields [apple, orange] as the highest fruits. If I wanted to pull apple's and orange's first_pass values into a new column using that test/analysis combination (resulting in [12.1, 19.1], is there a pandas way?

Comment: Such a powerful module. Thanks Stefan!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you meant

`'test' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`

To generate your first column, you can group by the test number, and compare each second pass score to the max score:

```
df['highest'] = df['second_pass'] == df.groupby('test')['second_pass'].transform('max')
```

For the second part, I don't have a clean solution, but here's a bit of an ugly one, first set the index to fruit:

```
df = df.set_index('fruit')
```

Next, find which rows have 'highest' set to True for each test, and return the a list of the indices that those rows have (which are the names of the fruits):

```
test1_max_fruits = df[df['test']==1&df['highest']].index.values.tolist()
test2_max_fruits = df[df['test']==2&df['highest']].index.values.tolist()
test3_max_fruits = df[df['test']==3&df['highest']].index.values.tolist()
```

Define a function to look at the test number then return the corresponding max_fruits that we just generated:

```
def max_fruits(test_num):

    if test_num == 1:
    return test1_max_fruits

    if test_num == 2:
    return test2_max_fruits

    if test_num == 3:
    return test3_max_fruits
```

Create a column and apply this function over your 'test' column:

```
df['highest_fruits'] = df['test'].apply(max_fruits)
```