# Index lookup for calculation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This is a follow-up of the following question: [Pandas DataFrame Window Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735915/pandas-dataframe-window-function)

```
  analysis  first_pass   fruit  order  second_pass  test units highest  \
0     full        12.1   apple      2         20.1     1     g    True   
1     full         7.1   apple      1         12.0     2     g   False   
2  partial        14.3   apple      3         13.1     1     g   False   
3     full        20.1  orange      2         20.1     1     g    True   
4     full        17.1  orange      1         18.5     2     g    True   
5  partial        23.4  orange      3         22.7     1     g    True   
6     full        23.1   grape      3         14.1     1     g   False   
7     full        17.2   grape      2         17.1     2     g   False   
8  partial        19.1   grape      1         19.4     1     g   False   

     highest_fruit        
0  [apple, orange] 
1         [orange] 
2         [orange] 
3  [apple, orange]   
4         [orange]  
5         [orange] 
6  [apple, orange]   
7         [orange] 
8         [orange]
```

In the original question, I was guided to the above table in which the highest fruit(s) for a given analysis and test combination was indicated by doing a transformation on the table (e.g. a **full analysis** on **test 1** resulted in apple and orange fruits having the highest second pass numbers).

I'm now trying to use this information to calculate those fruit(s) relative performance to their first pass.  For example, now that I know **apple and orange** are the highest fruits for a **full analysis, test 1**, I'd like to know if they improved over their first passes. (apple improved with a score of 20.1 on the second pass compared to 12.1 on their first_pass; likewise orange improved to 20.1 after scoring 19.1 on it's first pass).

I'd like a tables similar to the one below (1 = improved, 0 = no change, -1 worse):

```
  analysis  first_pass   fruit  order  second_pass  test units highest  \
0     full        12.1   apple      2         20.1     1     g    True   
1     full         7.1   apple      1         12.0     2     g   False   
2  partial        14.3   apple      3         13.1     1     g   False   
3     full        20.1  orange      2         20.1     1     g    True   
4     full        17.1  orange      1         18.5     2     g    True   
5  partial        23.4  orange      3         22.7     1     g    True   
6     full        23.1   grape      3         14.1     1     g   False   
7     full        17.2   grape      2         17.1     2     g   False   
8  partial        19.1   grape      1         19.4     1     g   False   

     highest_fruit        score_change_between_passes
0  [apple, orange]       {"apple" : 1, "orange" : 0}
1         [orange]       {"orange" : 1}
2         [orange]       {"orange" : -1}
3  [apple, orange]       {"apple" : 1, "orange" : 0}
4         [orange]       {"orange" " 1}
5         [orange]       {"orange" : -1}
6  [apple, orange]       {"apple" : 1, "orange" : 0}
7         [orange]       {"orange" : 1}
8         [orange]       {"orange" : -1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`np.sign()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
second_pass = df.groupby(['test', 'analysis']).apply(lambda x: {fruit: int(np.sign(x.loc[x.fruit==fruit, 'second_pass'].iloc[0] - x.loc[x.fruit==fruit, 'first_pass'].iloc[0])) for fruit in x.highest_fruit.iloc[0]}).reset_index()
df = df.merge(second_pass, on=['test', 'analysis'], how='left').rename(columns={0: 'second_pass_comp'})


  analysis  first_pass   fruit  order  second_pass  test units highest  \
0     full        12.1   apple      2         20.1     1     g    True   
1     full         7.1   apple      1         12.0     2     g   False   
2  partial        14.3   apple      3         13.1     1     g   False   
3     full        19.1  orange      2         20.1     1     g    True   
4     full        17.1  orange      1         18.5     2     g    True   
5  partial        23.4  orange      3         22.7     1     g    True   
6     full        23.1   grape      3         14.1     1     g   False   
7     full        17.2   grape      2         17.1     2     g   False   
8  partial        19.1   grape      1         19.4     1     g   False   

     highest_fruit         first_pass_highest_fruit           second_pass_comp  
0  [apple, orange]  {'orange': 19.1, 'apple': 12.1}  {'orange': 1, 'apple': 1}  
1         [orange]                 {'orange': 17.1}              {'orange': 1}  
2         [orange]                 {'orange': 23.4}             {'orange': -1}  
3  [apple, orange]  {'orange': 19.1, 'apple': 12.1}  {'orange': 1, 'apple': 1}  
4         [orange]                 {'orange': 17.1}              {'orange': 1}  
5         [orange]                 {'orange': 23.4}             {'orange': -1}  
6  [apple, orange]  {'orange': 19.1, 'apple': 12.1}  {'orange': 1, 'apple': 1}  
7         [orange]                 {'orange': 17.1}              {'orange': 1}  
8         [orange]                 {'orange': 23.4}             {'orange': -1}
```